# IIS 8.0 - Strip html tags from url (XSS protection)

Tags: security, iis, server, xss, iis-8

Here's the thing. I'm trying to protect my server from XSS Attacks (And so far with no trouble at all, changing HTTP response Headers and other things) But a Generic vulnerability is still going on, and it happens because in the URL some javascript code can be inserted

(i.e. `http://myhost.com/thisfile.jsp?<script>alert("hello")</script>`  )

when I type this, the response is HTTP 202 OK Status (It redirects to my 404 page). But I need to do one of these actions:

1. throw another HTTP Status (405, 500, Or any status giving an error)
2. Throw an error.

What can I do? Is there any way to strip the tags or recognize them via web.config file to throw an error?... I've been trying with the rewrite module and the request filtering with no success at all.

Thank you so much in advance, regards.

Comment: Do you actually see the script running? It's not very clear

Comment: Sorry @GilCohen, No. I don't see that script running because it immediately  it goes to the 404 custom error page. But if it allows the execution of the URL And the nessus vulnerability scan shows it as a medium risk. however, I solved it (easier than I thought it would be). And I'll post it in the answers. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you... I solved it and it was so easy (I can't believe i didn't try that first).

I went to IIS manager and then click on request filtering.

Then, on the "Rules" tab I added a "Filtering Rule". Applying to all file extensions and in the field "Deny Query String" I added `<script>`, `<scr+ipt>`, etc. So when the URL comes with a tag like that the connection is closed without showing 404 or any error page.

It worked and now the vulnerability scanner doesn't show any risk.